# How to connect an RJ45 cable into a RJ9 socket?

Tags: rj-45

Is there a way to use a UK phone with an RJ45 cable on a telephone system with an RJ9 socket? I bought a phone in the UK not knowing that the network back home required a different cable/plug. So, now I can't use the phone. I already went to a shop where they exchanged the RJ45 plugs on the cable for local ones, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you mean RJ-11 instead of RJ-9? RJ-11 is the "modular telephone jack" common on analog telephone line cords (at least in North America), and RJ-9 I believe is typically only used on the "curly" cord between the handset and the rest of the phone (the base).

Comment: Make and model?

Comment: Any jack can be replaced with another one...  The issue is the wiring in the jack

Comment: Where is “back home”? What make and model is your phone?

Answer (score 1):

Regular UK Phones don't have an RJ45, they have a modified RJ style with side lock, known as a [BS 6312 431A or 631A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_telephone_sockets) (wired 4-way or 6-way), usually just known as a British Telecom plug.

The other end [the one that goes into the phone] is a 6P4C or 6P2C, however [from the wikipedia link above]

> The connector on the phone is not standardized: the connector at the
>   wall is standardized by regulation, to allow individuals to use their
>   own phones (interconnection), but the wire from the phone to the wall
>   may be hard-wired to the phone, or use various connectors.
>
> Typically it will have a 6P4C or 6P2C modular connector at the
>   telephone end: this latter may be wired as per the RJ11 standard (with
>   pins 3 and 4), or it may be wired with pins 2 and 5, as a straight
>   through cable from the BT plug (which uses pins 2 and 5 for the line,
>   unlike RJ11, which uses pins 3 and 4). Thus cables are not in general
>   compatible between different phones, as the phone base may have a
>   socket with pins 2 and 5 (requiring a straight through cable), or have
>   an RJ11 socket (requiring a crossover cable).

The long & short of this means you will need to know the exact wiring scheme of the original cable in order to get it rewired correctly.
It would have been simpler to buy a converter plug/socket, of which there are many [examples](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/telephone-to-rj11-adapter-rz79l?ranMID=40341&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-EplBktrbAWaKu12IdDjrjw), as unless you have the original plug, you can't check the pin-out.

Wikipedia - [Telephone plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_plug) - lists the different national standards, so you know which adaptor you need[ed] - or you can buy a new RJ11 -> your national plug.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days RJ-11 was tip,ring, +pwr, -pwr. But I don't think the phone company provides power anymore. It is 2pair (4 wires)

An RJ-45 is simply another pair of wires (3pair 6 wires) with a thin shield wrapped around the wire bundle. In non commercial applications, only 2 wires are actually used so any connector with the appropriate 2 wires connected properly will work.

So yes - a RJ45 at one end can be connected to a RJ11 at the other as long as the correct pair of wires is matched to each socket.